# Asp.Net MVC controller action returning animated gif issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image-processing

I have a situation where I want to return an animated gif from an ASP.Net MVC controller action. I then want to construct an anchor tag like this:

```
<img src="/MyController/MyAction" id="company-logo" alt="Company Logo" />
```

The idea is that I want to be able to allow users to upload their own company logo and the controller action should retrieve their specific logo from the server.

However since my src attribute value does not end with .gif, the browser does not seem to be recognizing it as a gif and therefore does not animate it.

I know the controller action is returning it as a gif because when i load it from file I give it the file format as gif.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about getting my desired functionality?

Comment: Somewhat off topic but you might consider using the free features of http://imageresizing.net/ -- particularly setting caching options for the client side. If not, you might want to look into how to do caching to avoid transferring that image on every single request. This is easy to over look -- my apologies if you've already considered this issue.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Currently the images are actually stored as blobs in our database which we have realized is a big no-no if you want any hope of performance enhancements. We plan on starting to store the images on our file system and then caching them so this is actually a really good suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file extension would have nothing to do with it at all. Perhaps you need to make sure that your controller is setting the correct MIME type to `image/gif`? The browser can 'guess' at the content type sometimes, but it may not animate a gif in such a circumstance.